# Запретить запросы к адресу с портом 2710

Tags: linux, nginx, iptables

Есть установленный трекер на одном сервере. Обращаться за информацией к нему можно как через поддомен, так и через корневой адрес.

Т.е так `[udp|http]://sub.site.ru:2710` и так `[udp|http]://site.ru:2710` дадут одинаковую информацию.

ОП Debian 8. На нем привязка `Nginx + Apache` и `PHP5-FPM`.

Каким образом можно полностью отключить обращения к корневому адресу с портом 2710? В голову сразу пришла затея с iptables который умеет сбрасывать пакеты еще до запуска какого-либо процесса. Увы, не знаю как это реализовать. Кто знаток и умеет, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: если оба имени резолвятся в один ip-адрес, то — никак. ведь пакеты посылаются на ip-адрес, а не на доменное имя.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да на одном ip. Если с пакетами не выйдет, можно хотя бы 403 Forbidden отдать чтобы невозможно было получить информацию обращаясь к корневому домену?

Comment: силами netfilter-а, насколько мне известно — нет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin благодарю за содействие.

Answer (score 5):

Может помочь фильтрация по содержимому пакетов.
См. [man iptables-extensions](http://manpages.org/iptables-extensions/8), модуль `string`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2710 -m string --algo bm --string 'Host: site.ru' -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 2710 -m string --algo bm --string 'Host: site.ru' -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Данные правила фильтруют все пакеты приходящие на порт 2710 и содержащие строку "Host: site.ru". С помощью опций `--from` и `--to` можно сократить область поиска, но в данном случае думаю это необязательно.

Естественно если в пакете нет информации о запрашиваемом сайте, сервер не может отличить запросы к разным доменным именам. В протоколе **http** предусмотрено указание доменного имени сервера (это используется для виртуальных хостов). Поэтому для браузера фильтр должен срабатывать, но он сработает не сразу (открытие сокета пропускается), а когда будет передано доменное имя хоста. По **udp** могут слаться данные в любом формате, я предполагаю, что используется **http** с заголовком **Host**, если поверх **udp** используется другой протокол, фильтр его пропустит.

Comment: Сокращать область поиска нужно, поиск строки во ВСЕХ пакетах сервера обойдется очень дорого.

Comment: @Sanya_Zol, не дорого, информации от клиента к серверу идёт не так много, если он файлы передавать не собирается.

Comment: @sercxjo
Подключаюсь
`$fp = fsockopen('udp://site.ru', 2710, $errno, $errstr);`
Все равно доступно. http тоже доступен через fopen, но не доступен при обращении через адресную строку браузера.

Comment: @Max_Payne, дополнил ответ пояснениями. `fsockopen` с udp-адресом конечно должен работать в любом случае (если есть такой домен), так как это подготовительная операция, и клиент ещё никак не взаимодействует с севером.

Comment: @sercxjo благодарю за содействие. Придется все-таки новый IP выделять.

Comment: @Max_Payne, посмотрите сниффером, `tcpdump` или `wireshark`, в каком виде приходят реальные udp-пакеты на трекер, и есть ли там доменное имя.

Answer (score 0):

> Каким образом можно полностью отключить обращения к корневому адресу с портом 2710? В голову сразу пришла затея с iptables который умеет сбрасывать пакеты еще до запуска какого-либо процесса.

если оба имени резолвятся в один ip-адрес, то — никак. ведь пакеты посылаются на ip-адрес, а не на доменное имя.